# Emails not being delivered to Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am attempting to send emails from a Web App written in C#/ASP.NET.

I am trying to send both HTML and text version of the email.
However, when I attempt to send to a Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, AOL, etc. email address it does not show up in their inbox.

When I send strictly text, without the HTML alternate view, it delivers just fine.

Has anyone here had any experience with this?

The email is delivered fine to our Hosted Exchange server "@mxxx.com"

Thanks!

EDIT: One more thing. When the emails don't get delivered, we don't receive any type of failed delivery notification, it essentially disappears.

Code:

```
// email the user
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage("support@mxxx.com", user.EmailAddress);
                message.Bcc.Add("xxx@gmail.com");
                message.Bcc.Add("xxx@yahoo.com");
                message.Bcc.Add("xxx@hotmail.com");
                message.Subject = "Your \"mxxx.com\" password has been reset";
                message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("support@mxxx.com"));
                message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay |
                                                      DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
                message.Sender = new MailAddress("support@mxxx.com");

                string htmlbody = "<html><body><p>Dear " + name + ":</p>" +
                "<p>Your password at \"mxxx.com\" has been reset to: " + newPassword + "</p>" +
                </body></html>";

                var plainTextBody = "test plain text";

                AlternateView plainTextView =
                    AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
                        plainTextBody, message.BodyEncoding, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

                plainTextView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
                message.AlternateViews.Add(plainTextView);

                AlternateView htmlview =
                    AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
                        htmlbody, message.BodyEncoding, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

                htmlview.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

                message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlview);



                SmtpClient mailMan = new SmtpClient();
                mailMan.Send(message);
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but I suspect those services use html content as one of the factors in their spam filters -- spam is more effective when there's an html link to click on, and so is slightly more likely to use html. Combine that with anything not 100% perfect in terms of your smtp server's rDNS, DKIM, or SPF records, etc, and your message will go to a black hole. That's why I always recommend using a reputable e-mail marketing service, even for routine stuff like this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I see. We are definitely being sent into some black hole, there is no trace of the email being rejected or anything after it is sent.

Answer (score 0):

What if you avoid using AlternateView and specify that the body is HTML?
Consider testing the next snippet?:

```
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("support@mxxx.com", user.EmailAddress);
            message.Bcc.Add("xxx@gmail.com");
            message.Bcc.Add("xxx@yahoo.com");
            message.Bcc.Add("xxx@hotmail.com");
            message.Subject = "Your \"mxxx.com\" password has been reset";
            message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("support@mxxx.com"));
            message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay |
                                                  DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
            message.Sender = new MailAddress("support@mxxx.com");

            string htmlbody = "<html><body><p>Dear " + name + ":</p>" +
            "<p>Your password at \"mxxx.com\" has been reset to: " + newPassword + "</p>" +
            </body></html>";

            message.Body = htmlbody;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient mailMan = new SmtpClient();
            mailMan.Send(message);
```

Comment: I had it like that originally and the message still would not be delivered. It was received on our Hosted Exchange but the Text version was displayed instead of the HTML.

Comment: When you instantiate *message* set the *IsBodyHtml = true;* so *message.IsBodyHtml = true;* and then *mailMan.Send(message)*